# how to get the tier prices as well as quantities in the pop up after adding it to the cart?

Tags: magento-1.7

When I click "Add to cart" button, an ajax request is sent and a pop up is displayed with its image to say that the product has been added.
I want some more information about that product like I want to show the **next tier price** and **the quantity** upon which the customer would get some discount.
So I need both the quantity and the tier price .But I don't know how to get it.
This the file which is called in the ajax request..

```
 <?php
 require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
 class Excellence_Ajax_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
   {
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if($params['isAjax'] == 1){
        $response = array();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to find Product ID');
            }

            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );

            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $response['message'] = $message;
           $response['product_name'] = $this->__('%s', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                $response['product_image'] = $this->__('%s', Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(180));
                $this->loadLayout();
                $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
                Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $msg = "";
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $msg .= $message.'<br/>';
                }
            }

            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $msg;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }else{
        return parent::addAction();
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` class that is used on the frontend prices are displayed with the method `getTierPrices`.

In this method the products are retrieved via `$product->getFormatedTierPrice();`

So that should give us a hint on how to do this.

```
[...]
if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
    $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
    $response['message'] = $message;
    $response['product_name'] = $this->__('%s', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
    $response['product_image'] = $this->__('%s', Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(180));

    // here comes the tierprice code
    $prices = $product->getFormatedTierPrice(); // get tierprices as array

    if (is_array($prices)) {
        foreach ($prices as $price) {
            if ($params['qty'] <= $price['price_qty']) continue; // skip all quantities lower than what we currently have

            // set next price and qty in the response
            $response['product_tier_qty'] = $price['price_qty']; 
            $response['product_tier_price'] = $price['price'];
            break; //and break the loop
        }
    }

    [...]
    here the original code
```

Comment: Thanks @Sander Mangel It helped me getting 60% of my solution . Can you suggest how can I get the quantity of a particular product added to the cart by a customer so that I can show him the exact next tier price quantity.

Comment: `$response['product_tier_qty']` should have the next qty for tierprices

Comment: But first I want to calculate the quantity of the particular product which is added to cart. Then By comparing this quantity with the next tier price quantity I will show the customer that " buy ''x' more  and get discount upto 'y'. So I need to know quantity of the particular product in the cart.

Comment: ah ok, the qty added that time to the cart is found in `$params['qty']` if you need the absolute qty you'll need to fetch that from the quote items collection

Comment: yes exactly I want absolute qty for a particular product from the cart (qutoe items collection I guess). I have only the product_id. How can I find the quantity of the product from cart using its id ?

Comment: @KishorePatra I have limited time to debug and answer questions. Could you take a look yourself and see if you can fix it? If you have a concrete issue I'm more than willing to help

Comment: I can understand @Sander Mangel. Ok I have done somthing like..                                                                          `foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item){
                if($item->getProductId()== $params['product']){
                    echo $item->getQty();
                }                                                                                                  }`  Is it correct ?

Comment: @KishorePatra hm yeah looks pretty ok to me :)